# Where should I call post-login methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 app, I need to call after the login 2 stored procedure to get user-specific details... I've a Login controller that does this stuff

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserLogin user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    bool res = System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, user.Password);
    if (res)
    {
       Utente utente = commonRepository.GetProfiloUtente(user.UserName);

       if (utente != null)
       {
         Session["utente"] = utente;
       }

       DateTime dataLavorativa = commonRepository.GetGiornoLavorativoPrecedente(utente.IDInterno);

       Session["data_lavorativa"] = dataLavorativa;

       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
     }
     else
     {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
     }
   }
   return View("Index", user);
 }
```

This works when the user is not authenticated and he's forced to pass from login page...

Where should I put my code in order to call those methods when a user connects to the app but he already authenticated?

I can't put this in each Index action of each controller...
Thanks

Comment: So if I understand correctly what you need is if cookies exists and user comes to your page you want to fill the session data, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Global.asax - Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute method for this purpose.

```
public void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
bool isAuthenticated = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) 
        && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    if (isAuthenticated )
        {
            //Do call procedures
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excuse me but I get a NullReference Exception without the possibility to debug....

Comment: Which object is null? I modified the code, can you try it now

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that part... I adding the eventhandler in the App_Start instead of the controller... since I'm in integrated mode I can't access to session object in the PreRequestHandlerExecute, I've opted to create a BaseController and override it's OnAuthorization ... is this wrong? inside this method I read if it's already authenticated and if I've already a Session["user"] ...if not I take userID from the cookie and call the 2 stored procedure to retrieve data... can this be ok?
Thanks